# Undefined Element Returned From Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a class component which  makes an async call before `render()` and stores the result into its state. The async call is called before render with `componentWillMount()` which uses `this.renderData()`. The async response returns an array of arrays but in this case I am only interested in the first array. So I store the result `collections.first` into the state `arrayData`. I can successfully console.log the state `arrayData` which shows 8 elements (see screenshow). However, when I try to access an element with an index using `Array.at(index)` or `Array[index]` I get an undefined error.

How do I properly retrieve the index? The overall goal is to retrieve a value from the result and display an image in the render function `<img src={this.state.arrayData.at[2].url}> </img>`/ But Im unsure why Undefined is happening.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      arrayData: null,
    };
  }

  renderData = async () => {
      // async request code here which sets fetchURL and requestOptions
      const collections = await fetch(fetchURL, requestOptions).then((data) =>
        data.json()
      );
      if (collections ) {
        this.setState({ arrayData: collections.first });
      }
    }
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.renderData ();
  }

  render() {
     
     console.log(this.state.arrayData); // correctly outputs array of length 8 (see output below)
     console.log(this.state.arrayData[2]); // undefined error 
     console.log(this.state.arrayData.at(2); // undefined error

     return(
         // some render code 
         <img src={this.state.arrayData.at[2].url}> </img> // cant retrieve
    );
  }
}
```

Array output from response shows 8 items fine when logging as `this.state.arrayData`
[image]

Error Code when logging with `console.log(this.state.arrayData[2]);`

```
react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '2')
    at Gallery.render (Gallery.jsx:61:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26096:1)
```

Error Code when logging with `console.log(this.state.arrayData.at(2));`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'at')
    at Gallery.render (Gallery.jsx:61:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26096:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain what is happening here :

In the first time when you render the component the **this.state.arrayData** it's **undefined** , and after the data it's fetched from the server the component render again and you can see the result of the responce in your console , but when you try to access the the array at index 2 and the data is undefined you will get this error .

So the solution it's easy check if the **this.state.arrayData** it's true then display the component else make a loading component .

```
  render() {
    if (!this.state.arrayData) {
        return <h1>...Loading</h1>
    } 
     return(
         // some render code 
         <img src={this.state.arrayData.at[2].url}> </img> // cant 
      retrieve
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ah, it makes perfect sense to check the state of the data from the request because it is async. Thank you!